# backstretch.js duration out of sync with .animate() delay

Tags: jquery, animation, delay, duration, jquery-backstretch

Preface: I am new to writing my own jQuery code and have [had help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26950616/how-to-possible-to-combine-these-variables-and-animate-functions) writing the animateContinously() function below.

I'm using [backstretch.js](https://github.com/srobbin/jquery-backstretch) to have a full browser viewport/background slideshow and [jQuery animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) function to change the color (with the help of the [jquery-color.js plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color)) of the text that shows on top of the backstretch controlled images, depending on which backstretch image is showing. It works, but the backstretch() duration and animate() delay are out of sync if I set them to the same number, ie: 5000 (5 seconds). So I tried offsetting them by 1000 (1 second) and the text and backstretch images fade-in/out at the exact same time, as desired...but after 15 or so transitions they fall out of sync again.

Any ideas/help as to why the same duration & delay time amount doesn't work? And/or why the 1 second offset works at first and then falls out of sync? Here is my code:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-color.js"></script>
<script src="backstretch.js"></script>
<script>
  $.backstretch([
  "_img/bg01.jpg",
  "_img/bg02.jpg"
  ], {
  fade: 1000,
  duration: 4000
  });
</script>
<script>
    function animateContinuously($element, attr, values) {
    var i = 0, count = values.length;
    setInterval(function() {
        i = (i + 1) % count;
        var props = {};
        props[attr] = values[i];
        $element.animate(props, 1000);
    }, 5000); // // in sync with backstretch() if 1000 more, but falls out of sync after 15-18 transitions

    animateContinuously($("#color-change1"), 'color', ['#de7056', '#4ec67f']);
    animateContinuously($("#color-change2"), 'svgFill', ['#de7056', '#4ec67f']);
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the cycling of the background images and `setInterval()` are not tied together, they are just always going to fall out of sync. The solution is to abandon `setInterval()`, and instead use [the events triggered by the Backstretch plugin](https://github.com/srobbin/jquery-backstretch). You would start your animations when the "backstretch.before" event is triggered.

```
$(window).on('backstretch.before', function() {
    // Start animations here.
});
```

If the number of images, colors, and other values to be animated are all the same, you could have:

```
var TRANSITION_DURATION = 1000,
    PAUSE_DURATION = 4000;

// Note: These arrays should all have the same length.
var IMAGES = ['_img/bg01.jpg', '_img/bg02.jpg'],
    COLORS = ['#de7056', '#4ec67f'];

var index = 0;

$.backstretch(IMAGES, {
    fade: TRANSITION_DURATION,
    duration: PAUSE_DURATION
});

$(window).on('backstretch.before', function() {
    index = (index + 1) % IMAGES.length;
    $('#color-change1').animate({ backgroundColor: COLORS[index] }, TRANSITION_DURATION);
    $('#color-change2').animate({ svgFill: COLORS[index] }, TRANSITION_DURATION);
});
```

[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mjx4m30p/)

If the arrays of values are not all the same length, you could do something like in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zwvdrawj/2/).

Comment: Wow! Thanks again. This is so very helpful. My arrays will always be the same length so your first example is what I will work with. I did look at the 2nd jsfiddle as well but am confused as to why the #999999 (grey) color gets applies 2nd to #color-change1 when #43c67 (orange) is 2nd in the array?

Comment: @codeview - It's because I had the initial color for both shapes as white. I have now changed it so they are both initially `#de7056` (the first color in the arrays). The `i` variables start out at zero, but they are incremented before the animation, so the first time the animation is run, it transitions to the second color in the arrays (because `i` = 1).